# Fetching Comments of Comments with the LinkedIn API

Tags: linkedin-api

The LinkedIn docs state how to collect comments of a comment [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/network-update-social-actions#retrieve-comments-on-comments), but they seem to be incorrect. It says to make a GET request that looks like this:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/socialActions/urn:li:comment:(activity:6273189577469632512,6275822846992351232)/comments
```

but when I try that all I get back is a 400 error with the message:

> Syntax exception in path variables

Is this the correct formatting of the comment urn? I've tried encoding it like with other requests, but that returns back the same result. Seeing a working example of this request would really help.

Comment: @clavin-i hi did you change `:` with `%3A`, please if you can give me the full path url with variables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After talking to LinkedIn API's support, I have the answer to why this wasn't working. A lot of the documentation contains these notes:

> All API requests are represented in protocol 2.0.0 and require the
>   header X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0.

I thought that those notes meant that all v2 requests are meant to have their headers contain X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0, but in actuality, it is only the endpoints where that is specified in the pages of the documentation. In other words, using that header for endpoints where it isn't needed can cause some of the requests to fail in ways that aren't clear from the error message. Removing that from the header gave the correct response.

Comment: I was getting this issue when fetching videos at `rest/videos/{urn}`.  Turns out dropping the Protocol header resolved it. Even though it is explicitly listed in their example documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/videos-api?view=li-lms-2022-06&tabs=curl

Answer (score 1):

In fact the v2 protocol ask to url encode variable path.
So better to stay in v2 protocol and url encode the "urn:li:comment:...."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/api-guide/concepts/protocol-version#single-resource-key